# how to remove the string

Tags: php

```
$data[2]=UploadPic/'nike--1.jpg;UploadPic/'nike--1-8221-2.jpg;UploadPic/'nike--u65B0-8221-3.jpg
```

i want to remove `UploadPic`. namely:

```
 $data[2]=/'nike--1.jpg;/'nike--1-8221-2.jpg;/'nike--u65B0-8221-3.jpg
```

how do i do?

Comment: What's your current code / what did you try?

Comment: i used the substr().but stucked.

Answer (score 5):

```
$data[2] = str_replace("UploadPic","",$data[2]);
```